# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine when running with ShellExecuteA

Tags: java, visual-c++, shellexecute

I'm trying to make a (modded) Minecraft custom launcher and I've got a problem with launching java with special command.

I'm using:

`ShellExecuteA(NULL, string("open").c_str(), bity.c_str(), launch.c_str(), NULL, SW_RESTORE);`

Where "bity" is path to Javaw: `C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe`
and "launch" is a loong parameter: http://pastebin.com/T0knTfzE (seriously, it's very long).

And the point is that when I'm launching it with `ShellExecuteA`, Java shows

> "Could not create the Java Virtual Machine."

BUT when i'm running that command (bity+launch) outside my program in cmd.exe it works!

Please, help me!

EDIT: ---

> OS: Windows 7 x64 ---
>   RAM: 8GB ---
>   Java 7 version 51 (newest)

Comment: That's an error from javaw. Could you try giving it the path of the javaw for your actual JRE, e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe or similar? No idea why that would make any difference, though, unless it's being launched from an odd environment missing some registry. (I've also never seen ShellExecute used to launch a process like that, as opposed to opening a document or URL, but you seem to be past that.)

Comment: %appdata% doesn't do what you hope it does.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Rup, I tried to give it a path to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe, the same result...

Comment: Hans Passant, I think that those parameters are going to Java, which should know what to do with them (%appdata%). Correct me if it's wrong.